# How to convert a hash to string

Tags: ruby, hash

input: contact = {"name" => "White", "age" => 22, "country" => "India"}

expected output: "age=22country=Indianame=White"

Comment: basically 1) arranging the hash in alphabetically and do "key1=val1key2=val2key3=val3"

Comment: What is the use of such output?  Why will you have `age` in hash called `contact`?

Comment: you should try to provide tries or something, SO is not about having the job done for you.

Comment: @Ashaeva sure you don't want delimiters, e.g. `"key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3"`?

Comment: @Stefan yes I don't want them :)

Comment: @WandMaker That was just an example hash

Comment: @Ashaeva I know its an example, but it is not very useful example.  Your output is pretty much useless for any practical purposes.  People will downvote the question if they feel its not properly asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is by using `.map`

```
contact = {"name" => "White", "age" => 22, "country" => "India"}
contact.sort.map{|pair| pair.join('=')}.join
 => "age=22country=Indianame=White"
```

Edit: didn't notice the implied sorting requirement in output.

Answer (score 3):

```
{"name" => "White", "age" => 22, "country" => "India"}.sort.map{|i| i.join('=')}.join
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = ""
input.each do |key, value|
  string += "#{key}=#{value}"
end


puts string
# age=22country=Indianame=White
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contact.keys.sort.map {|k| "#{k}=#{contact[k]}"}.join
```